# iText set cell height to height set in Excel row

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi

I am using iText 7.1.15 in combination with Apache POI 4.1.1 to create a PDF from an Excel sheet.
The rows in the sheet are set to a specific height in centimeters to fit correctly on an A4 page when printed.
However when I set the cell height via iText and have a look at the result the row in the PDF table isn't exactly as high as in Excel.
I am using `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.getHeightInPoints()` and set this value to my PDF table cell using `com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell.setHeight()`.
Inspecting the result however the row height in my PDF is slightly different than expected.
And some content (the last row in my sample) event gets truncated (I guess because the cell isn't high enough)...

What am I doing wrong here?

You can find the complete sample here at [Github](https://github.com/sven-olding/itext-test)

PDF:
[image: In PDF]

Excel:
[image: Excel]

```
for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    if (row == null) {
        continue;
    }
    float heightInPoints = row.getHeightInPoints();
    System.out.println("Row: " + (rowNum + 1) + ": " + heightInPoints + "pt = " + heightInPoints * PT_TO_CM + "cm");
    for (int cellNum = 0; cellNum < numCols; cellNum++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell pdfCell = new com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell();
        pdfCell.add(new Paragraph(cell.getStringCellValue()));
        pdfCell.setHeight(heightInPoints);
        pdfCell.setBorder(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
        table.addCell(pdfCell);
    }
}
```

```
package com.gi.itext;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.SolidBorder;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.AreaBreakType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class App {
    private static final String OUTPUT = "./target/output.pdf";
    private static final String INPUT = "/input.xlsx";
    private static final float PT_TO_CM = 0.0352778f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        File file = new File(OUTPUT);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(INPUT);
             Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is)) {
            PdfDocument pdfDoc;
            try {
                pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(OUTPUT));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            pdfDoc.addNewPage();
            Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);

            for (int sheetNum = 0; sheetNum < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNum++) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNum);
                if (sheetNum > 0) {
                    doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
                }
                int numCols = getNumberOfColumns(sheet);
                float[] columnWidth = new float[numCols];
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    float columnWidthInPixels = sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(j);
                    double columnWidthInPoints = columnWidthInPixels * 0.75d;
                    columnWidth[j] = (float) columnWidthInPoints;
                }
                Table table = new Table(columnWidth);
                table.useAllAvailableWidth();

                for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
                    if (row == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    float heightInPoints = row.getHeightInPoints();
                    System.out.println("Row: " + (rowNum + 1) + ": " + heightInPoints + "pt = " + heightInPoints * PT_TO_CM + "cm");
                    for (int cellNum = 0; cellNum < numCols; cellNum++) {
                        Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                        com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell pdfCell = new com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell();
                        pdfCell.add(new Paragraph(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                        pdfCell.setHeight(heightInPoints);
                        pdfCell.setBorder(new SolidBorder(0.5f));
                        table.addCell(pdfCell);
                    }
                }
                doc.add(table);
            }

            doc.close();
            pdfDoc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int getNumberOfColumns(Sheet sheet) {
        int firstRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        for (int rowNum = firstRowNum; rowNum < lastRowNum; rowNum++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            if (row == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (row.getLastCellNum() > -1) {
                return row.getLastCellNum();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please specify how you measured and compared the height of the cell in the `PDF` and `Excel` respectively? I used `Snipping Tool` (Windows 10) to measure the  height of PDF cell (zoom set at 100%) and it pretty much measured upto `2.5 cm`.

Comment: About the truncation of content in the last cell, I suggest using a custom font size:
`pdfCell.add(new Paragraph(cell.getStringCellValue()).setFontSize(10))` instead of relying on the default font size set by `iText`. Setting a custom font size solved the truncation issue for me.

Comment: Due to the lack of a printer I've measured using a screen ruler. Setting the font size to the one used in Excel does not help with the truncated text in row 3 `pdfCell.add(new Paragraph(cell.getStringCellValue()).setFontSize(cellStyle.getFont().getFontHeightInPoints()));`

Comment: Comparing the results when Excel file saved as PDF and my result also differs, I don't understand exactly why

Comment: @dobobird I've solved the issue with the "truncated" text, the font size was actually bigger than the resulting size of the table row, I fixed that part of my problem